# Stream mp3 file from Ubuntu source using python program (ideally) to Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, streaming, raspberry-pi, rtsp

I am a newcomer to Linux and Python and I am trying to attempt to stream an audio file (preferably MP3) from a Ubuntu source computer to a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian for immediate playback.

I have explored various options such as gStreamer, Live555, VLC player and PulseAudio. I have also investigated TCP, RTP and RTSP. However I am struggling to get anything working properly. It seems as though I need to set up a RTSP Server using the computer and the Raspberry Pi as a RTSP client and I am not sure how to do this.

I'm wondering if anyone has any simple instructions or guides as to how to set up even a basic version of this with a specific MP3 file?

Comment: Hi - there is a Raspberry Pi specific site you can ask questions on. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use netcat and mplayer for this

#### In the Raspberry Pi

`sudo apt-get install mplayer`

`nc -l -p 1234 | mplayer -cache 8192 -`

#### In your PC

`cat your.mp3 | nc [RASPI IP] 1234`

It's very crude, however it's very easy. Just take care that you'll need to relaunch netcat (nc) from each side everytime you need to play a new MP3.

Cheers

---

Source: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/send-audio-over-network-888169/